# Using Alias in the WHERE Clause SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I'm trying to do is narrow the query down in the from clause by using WHERE LienType = 'No Private' from the Private Benefits alias created from the case statement. How would I do so?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientId
,ClientFirstName
,ClientLastName
, Case when (select COUNT(*)
              from FullProductView fpvb 
              where fpvb.clientid=fpva.clientid 
              and fpvb.Lientype ='Private Lien') = 0 then 'No Private' 
         else 'Private Yes' end 'Private Benefits'
from fullproductview fpva 
WHERE CaseId = 420
Order By 'Private Benefits'
```

Comment: I think solving his issue is not duplicate but a restructure of the query:

    SELECT
     ClientId,
     ClientFirstName,
     ClientLastName,
     CASE
      WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN LienType = 'Private Lien' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
      THEN 'Private Yes'
      ELSE 'Private No'
     END PrivateBenefits
    FROM
     FullProductView FPVA
    WHERE
     CaseId = 420
    GROUP BY
     ClientId,
     ClientFirstName,
     ClientLastName
    ORDER BY
     CASE
      WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN LienType = 'Private Lien' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
      THEN 'Private Yes'
      ELSE 'Private No'
     END;

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly. The only two options to use a calculated field on the WHERE clause is to create a view, with the calculated field, or a subquery. I think that to create a view is the easy way.

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_MyView AS
SELECT DISTINCT ClientId
,ClientFirstName
,ClientLastName
, Case when (select COUNT(*)
              from FullProductView fpvb 
              where fpvb.clientid=fpva.clientid 
              and fpvb.Lientype ='Private Lien') = 0 then 'No Private' 
         else 'Private Yes' end 'Private Benefits'
from fullproductview fpva 
WHERE CaseId = 420
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT * from vw_MyView WHERE LienType = 'No Private' Order By 'Private Benefits'
```

Also is not a good idea to use spaces on field names. You need to check if this works with your database engine (wich you don't mention).

Comment: How would you structure the view?